# Emit to every room a socket is in using _rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to emit to an array of rooms (specifically all the rooms a socket is in) without a for loop? Similar to how you can join with `socket.join([roomArray])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself (with help from the Socket.IO Slack). Yes, it is!

**With a for loop**

```
// You can rename the room variable whatever you want
for (const room of Object.keys(socket.rooms)) {
        socket.to(room).emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
}
```

**Without a for loop**

You can use the native `_rooms` property of a socket

```
// _rooms will be cleared once it has been emitted to
socket._rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);
// console.log(socket._rooms) = ['abc', 'efg', ...]
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
// console.log(socket._rooms) = []
```